# The photo failed to upload. Laravel Jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

Getting a 401 (Unauthorized) on the dashboard while trying to upload a profile picture. App URL is set properly and the feature is uncommented. the console which shows a post request to site.com/livewire/upload-file is showing unauthorized and the response is empty. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvTtA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your tmp directory.
In php.ini, this is this line : sys_temp_dir = .....
In the code with : sys_get_temp_dir()

Verify if the directory exist

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about developer mode then it has to do with your URL. Start up the artisan server (within your project directory in your console/terminal write: "php artisan serve") and then go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/. You'll be able to upload the photo in a jiffy.